# How to push different IntentViewController in Sirikit extension based on the Intent type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, sirikit

I am trying to integrate `Sirikit` extension into my existing iOS app.
For this, I am going to use two different types of intent.

```
INSendMessageIntent - to send message from Siri through my app.
INSendPaymentIntent - for making a payment
```

For both the intent types, I was to use custom & different `IntentUI`.

But how to push different `ViewController` in Sirikit extension for based on the Intent type i.e., if I say `Make payment using MyWorld` then one `PayViewController` has to be pushed and when I say `Send message using MyWorld` then `MessageViewController` has to be pushed.

I want to choose View controller dynamically at runtime based on the Intent type (i.e., `INSendMessageIntent` or `INSendPaymentIntent`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to support more than one function of Siri by creating independent targets. The payments UI is one IntentsUI target, and the messages UI is another one. Info plists for each define which target looks after which type of intent.